Is there any way to stop zooming in a recorded video which has a zooming effect?
I am currently working on a computer vision project related to cricket. My goal is to detect the ball, determine its position in each frame, and then plot the trajectory of the ball in a 3D view. However, I've encountered an issue with the recorded video, as it has a zooming effect. This makes it difficult to accurately calculate the position of the ball in relation to the cricket pitch. Initially, the entire cricket pitch is detected in the first few frames.
Full Pitch Image:

However, as the video zooms in, only half of the frame is captured,
Half Pitch Image:

making it impossible to correctly calculate the position of the ball in reference to the full pitch view.
I'm looking for a way to mitigate this zooming effect.

deleted question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78598029/how-to-disable-zoom-on-a-recorded-video-for-object-detection (user Joy Karmoker)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

An easy solution:
The zoom can be approximated by an affine transformation. You could estimate the transformation between first and last frame (using cv::estimateAffinePartial2D()) and therefore obtain a transformation matrix to apply to the coordinates of the ball between these two frames. You could interpolate for the intermediate frames. If you are lucky this is good enough for your example.
